# python list index out of bound

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hello this is my first time here!

as a assignment i got this: Now make a new function cumulative_sum that returns a new list where the i-th element is the sum of the first i+1 elements from the original list. For example, the cumulative sum of [4, 3, 6] is [4, 7, 13].

so i have written this code:

```
list_1 = [4, 6, 3]

def cumulative_sum(a_list):
    list_2 = []
    list_2.append(a_list[0])
    x = 1
    y = 0
        for i in a_list:
            if len(a_list) == x:
               break
            else:
                var1 = list_2[x]
                var2 = a_list[y]
                var3 = var1 + var2
                list_2.append(var3)
                x +=1
                y +=1
                return list_2
print cumulative_sum(list_1)
```

however i keep getting a index out of bound error even though  I have a bound check like:

```
        if len(a_list) == x:
        break
```

excuse my english! and any other tips on my code are welcome

this is the traceback:

```
 IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 /Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.4.1.1975.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/py3compat.pyc in execfile(fname, *where)
202             else:
203                 filename = fname
--> 204             __builtin__.execfile(filename, *where)

/Users/arkin/programming/multadd.py in <module>()
 97             return list_2
 98 
---> 99 print cumulative_sum(list_1)
100 
101 

/Users/arkin/programming/multadd.py in cumulative_sum(a_list)
 89             break
 90         else:
---> 91             var1 = list_2[x]
 92             var2 = a_list[y]
 93             var3 = var1 + var2
```

Answer (score 5):

You cannot assign an element into a list at an index that does not yet exist. You should use `append` to do that.

```
def cumulative_sum(l):
    total = 0          # initialize the total to zero
    cumulative = []    # initialize an empty list
    for num in l:      # iterate over each number in original list
        total += num   # calculate the cumulative total to this element
        cumulative.append(total)   # append to the cumulative list
    return cumulative
```

With your example input and output

```
>>> cumulative_sum([4,3,6])
[4, 7, 13]
```

**Edit**
The shorter way to do this is to use a few Python libraries

```
import itertools
import operator

def cumulative_sum(l):
    return list(itertools.accumulate(l, operator.add))
```

Comment: is This is a shorter way to do this? and would this work on every list? thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes I will write a shorter way to do it, I just wanted to write it step by step since you seem to be relatively new to Python. And yes it will work for any numeric list.

Comment: +1 for the concise answer, and upvote for the pythonic variation!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Cyber's answer, which is a great, concise answer (though not very pythonic ;), to answer why your original code didn't work: you simply had your `[x]` and `[y]` subscripts flipped when you extracted the values for `var1` and `var2`. Otherwise it actually worked fine. Here's your corrected code:

```
def cumulative_sum(a_list):
    list_2 = []
    list_2.append(a_list[0])

    x = 1
    y = 0

    for i in a_list:
        print x,y,i             # added for debugging purposes

        if len(a_list) == x:
            break
        else:
            var1 = list_2[y]    # your code had [x] here
            var2 = a_list[x]    # your code had [y] here
            var3 = var1 + var2

            list_2.append(var3)
            x +=1
            y +=1

    return list_2


print cumulative_sum([4,3,6])   # outputs [4, 7, 13]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another one:

```
def cumulative_sum(lst):
    new_lst = []
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        new_lst.append(sum(lst[:i + 1]))
    return new_lst
```

slicing doesn't have this index out of bound problem.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
s = [4,5,6]

y = []

for i in s:

    if s.index(i) == 0:
       y.append(i)
    else:
       t = y[len(y) -1] + i;
       y.append(t)

>>> y
[4, 9, 15]
```

Simples!